# How to get all results from dynamic checkbox list in Powershell form

Tags: powershell

The larger code generates a list of operating systems installed on machines we maintain. That list is stored as $WindowsList. Here's what I have so far to assemble the list of checkboxes. It works to build the form, but I'm realizing that I can't actually get all the data out this way.

```
Foreach ($OS in $WindowsList) {
    $SelectOS = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
    $SelectOS.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,$FormHeight)
    $SelectOS.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
    $SelectOS.Text = "$OS"
    $Form.Controls.Add($SelectOS)
}
```

How do I dynamically build this list and get its results?

I've tried a few iterations of ideas, but nothing has given notable results. The code sample above only provides the results for the last item. I understand why it is doing that; I just don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: `$CheckBoxes = $Form.Controls.Where({$_ -is [System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox]]})`

Comment: That was far more elegant than I expected, thank you.

I ran with this solution and further refined it using the AccessibleDescription field, resulting in this creating exactly the return string i needed:

$Form.Controls.Where{$_.AccessibleDescription -eq "WindowsSelect" -and $_.Checked -eq "True"}.Text